# Laplace Transform of non integrable function

Tags: lebesgue-integral, laplace-transform

Consider $$f(t)=\begin{cases}1 &x\text{ is rational}\\0&x\text{ is irrational}\end{cases}$$What is the Laplace transform of $f(t)$? I expect it to be $0$ but I am not able to prove it. Does such a function $f(t)$ qualify as a Null function?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $f$ is zero outside a set of zero Lebesgue measure, so for any measurable $g$ we have $\int fg = 0$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate. What is a lebesgue measure?

Comment: how do you define the value of $C = \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-t} dt$ ? with the "usual" definition based on Lebesgue measure, it is $0$, and hence $\int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st} dt = 0$ for every $Re(s) > 0$.